# Выброс IllegalMonitorStateException в StampedLock

Tags: java, многопоточность, lock, блокировки

Изучая StampedLock тестировал приведенный ниже код:

```
public class StampedLockDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StampedLock sl = new StampedLock();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        // Runnable as lambda - optimistic read
        Runnable r1 = () -> {
            long stamp = sl.tryOptimisticRead();
            try {
                System.out.println("In optimistic lock " + sl.validate(stamp));
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("In optimistic lock " + sl.validate(stamp));
            } finally {
                sl.unlock(stamp);
            }
        };

        new Thread(r1).start();

        //executor.submit(r1);
        //executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Если я создам пул потоков и воспользуюсь интерфейсом `ExecutorService`: `executor.submit(r1);`, то данный код отработает и не выбросит исключение.
Однако если создать и запустить объект потока : `new Thread(r1).start();`, то, дойдя до разблокировки, выбросится исключение

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlockRead(StampedLock.java:683)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlock(StampedLock.java:698)
    at Reentrantlock.StampedLockDemo.lambda$main$0(StampedLockDemo.java:25)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Не могу понять в чем разница между двумя этими реализациями: почему первый не выбросит исключение, а второй (дойдя до `sl.unlock(stamp);`) - выбросит.  Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `executor.submit(r1);` тоже бросает исключение, просто оно "съедается" самим экзекьютором. Даже если ты поменяешь Runnable чтобы он гарантированно бросал исключение, ты его не увидишь:
   `Runnable r1 = () -> {throw new RuntimeException();}`

Попробуй "получить" значение от запущенного потока и ты увидишь ровно то же исключение, что и для Thread:

```
Future<?> result = executor.submit(r1);
executor.shutdown();
result.get(); // IllegalMonitorStateException
```

2. Исключение бросается, потому что `tryOptimisticRead` не берёт lock. Он нужен только чтобы проверить, что со времени вызовы этого метода, не происходила write-блокировка, т.е. ты берёшь stamp, потом читаешь значения необходимых тебе переменных и проверяешь что не происходила ли write-блокировка tryOptimisticRead и текущим местом. Если write брался, то validate вернёт false. Это значит, что прочитанные значения невалидные, нужно читать снова.

```
System.out.println("In optimistic lock " + sl.validate(stamp)); // true
writeLockStamp = sl.writeLock();
sl.unlock(writeLockStamp); // отпустили write-блокировку
System.out.println("In optimistic lock after exclusive lock: " + sl.validate(stamp)); // false
```

Comment: премного благодарен!!